# Cconvert Netbeans project to Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have developed a very big Java application in NetBeans. Now I have Eclipse IDE, and I want to migrate my project from NetBeans to Eclipse IDE. Is there any procedure for that?

Please give me an advice for configuring NetBeans project into Eclipse IDE.

Comment: What is your project? Web application? It's depends!~

Comment: no its desktop application and also i have built.xml file and when i try to use this file with ant in eclipse that give me error that javac task not defined..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a full automatic process for that.
[This answer](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg18918.html) summarizes it well:

> The best thing for you to do is go through the tutorial in the Eclipse Help that teaches you how Projects are configured in Eclipse, including examples of several types of typical existing-project situations.
>   That will give you the base understanding to successfully set up your project in Eclipse.
>   The "`From Ant build file`" import is a nice attempt, but you have to realize it can't possibly interpret every kind of build, especially when it is not obvious what targets are really interesting.
>   Go through the tutorials in `Help Contents > Java Development User Guide > Getting Started`. They are simple and short enough but will get you very far.

---

For more advanced Netbeans projects (not exactly your situation, but I mention it there just in case), there was a [SOC proposal](http://wiki.eclipse.org/NetBeans_in_Eclipse)

> The plugins models for Eclipse and NetBeans are very similar yet different.
>   This project would provide the ability to run and embed a minimal NetBeans environment within Eclipse -- as Eclipse plugins-- , and support running NetBeans plugins like Matisse (Swing UI painter) or Coyote (dynamic languages toolkit).

But it didn't go very far: [Matisse4MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-5.html) is much more mature.

Comment: .. Thanks A lot.. but there is a quite different structure of built.xml file for netbeans and myeclipse project. As i commented eariler when i try to make project with option "java project from existing Ant BuiltFile" it gives me javac task not defined..

Comment: @water: which is why my answer is essentially to make a new Eclipse project and study how to replicate the Netbeans settings without trying to directly use Netbeans `build.xml`. The second part of my answer wasn't directly related to your case.